# Trying to send info acquired from html form to email using Flask Python

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to send info i get from form to a specific email adress.I got app password from Google. It doesn't send anything to my email. The code used for emailing works seperately so that's not a problem.Password and username is correct.It seems like data is received,but it just doesn't send it to email.
This is from my main.py

```
def send_email(name, email, phone, message):
    smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    smtp_port = 587
    smtp_username = 'sara@gmail.com'
    smtp_password = 'password'

    from_email = 'sara@gmail.com'
    to_email = 'sara@gmail.com'
    subject = 'Hello!'
    body = f'Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nPhone: {phone}\nMessage:{message}'
    message = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as smtp:
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
        smtp.sendmail(from_email, to_email, message)
```

And this is my contact.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
            <meta name="description" content="" />
            <meta name="author" content="" />
            <title>Clean Blog - Start Bootstrap Theme</title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='assets/favicon.ico') }}" />
            <!-- Font Awesome icons (free version)-->
            <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/js/all.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- Google fonts-->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
            <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            {% include "header.html" %}
    
            <!-- Page Header-->
    <header
      class="masthead"
      style="background-image: url('../static/assets/img/contact-bg.jpg')"
    >
      <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5">
        <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
            <div class="page-heading">
                {% if msg_sent %}
              <h1>Successfully sent your message</h1>
              {% else: %}
              <h1>Contact Me</h1>
              {% endif %}
              <span class="subheading">Have questions? I have answers.</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Main Content-->
    <main class="mb-4">
      <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
        <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
            <p>
              Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send me a message and
              I will get back to you as soon as possible!
            </p>
            <div class="my-5">
              <!-- * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *-->
              <!-- * * Simplified SB Contact Form for the Tutorial* *-->
              <!-- Solution: change url for the action to 'contact'-->
              <form
                id="contactForm"
                name="sentMessage"
                action="{{ url_for('contact') }}"
                method="post"
              >
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input
                    class="form-control"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter your name..."
                    required
                  />
                  <label for="name">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input
                    class="form-control"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email..."
                    required
                  />
                  <label for="email">Email address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <input
                    class="form-control"
                    id="phone"
                    name="phone"
                    type="tel"
                    placeholder="Enter your phone number..."
                    required
                  />
                  <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                  <textarea
                    class="form-control"
                    id="message"
                    name="message"
                    placeholder="Enter your message here..."
                    required
                    style="height: 12rem"
                  ></textarea>
                  <label for="message">Message</label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <button
                  class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase"
                  id="submitButton"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  Send
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
            {% include "footer.html" %}
            <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            
            <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/scripts.js') }}"></script>


           

            <script src="https://cdn.startbootstrap.com/sb-forms-latest.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The only thing I'm getting is

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:01] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:01] "GET /static/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:01] "GET /static/assets/img/home-bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:05] "GET /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:05] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:05] "GET /static/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:05] "GET /static/assets/img/contact-bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:11] "POST /contact HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Sara 
sara@gmail.com
03456789
cv
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:11] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:11] "GET /static/js/scripts.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2024 23:34:11] "GET /static/assets/img/contact-bg.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to call function send_email(name,email,phone,message) in function contact().